# Wheezy -> Jessie: Command Line Slow to Appear

Tags: login

I just upgraded a Pi from wheezy to jessie.

Since doing so I've noticed that there's a noticeable lag -- about 10 seconds -- between the final output of the last login information (the stuff which ends with there being "...ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY...") and the command line itself appearing.

The same change is apparent when I log in via SSH.

This isn't a big deal, but given all the other changes that the upgrade made which I had to resolve, I want to make sure there's not some problem lurking in the weeds behind this short delay.

I checked syslog and the auth logs and didn't notice anything odd.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies, but I forgot I also installed the node version manager, nvm, right before I started down the laborious process of upgrading from wheezy to jessie.

That extra delay in logging in I'm noticing is due to nvm being initialized. That occurs via the .bashrc file. So it's simply something you have to live with if you want to use nvm and don't want to have to configure it manually every time you want to use it.

Comment: That sounds odd. Might I suggest a bash alias to start nvm when needed, rather than have it waste time every restart?

Comment: Good idea. But then I'd have to remember to execute the alias :).